# Win32-OpenSSH - random error message (error in libcrypto)

Tags: ssh

I have a landscape as below:
SFTP server with OpenSSH, a client PC to connect to it using public key. After connection is made, it will execute some scripts for business purposes.
The connection is, to be honest, usually smooth. But in some random days, it gives me the message:

> fatal: ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to [client IP address]: error in libcrypto

I have been searching all over the web but no answer so far. I wonder if anyone encountered this problem before? Please help. Thanks.

[Log file is here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/files/766084/sshd.log.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Your Win32-OpenSSH version is pretty outdated, you should download a new one here: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases. Any bugs with libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib should also be addressed there by opening a ticket. They use precompiled version of OpenSSL libs in their project, which is almost 
guaranteed to cause various errors (unless the guy who compiles the release of Win32-OpenSSH is lucky to have exactly the same OS, VS version & CPU model as one, who created those `.lib` file they use). My Visual Studio 2016 failed to build their project, showing errors in those particular libraries. But as I've said there is a chance that their release version won't be buggy, so I suggest you try it

Comment: Thanks. In fact I use 0.0.7.0 which is pretty new (lastest version is 0.0.9.0 just released several days ago). I also create tickets there but they seem pretty busy. Can you explain more about `They use precompiled version of OpenSSL libs in their project, which is almost guaranteed to cause various errors (unless the guy who compiles the release of Win32-OpenSSH is lucky to have exactly the same OS, VS version & CPU model as one, who created those .lib file they use)` because I'm not a coding guy. How can a precompiled version could make problems like this one?

Comment: @nightwish47 Sure! [Here are the files, which cause errors](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/tree/L1-Prod/contrib/win32/openssh/OpenSSLSDK/1.0.2d/x64/Release/lib) - they are supposedly taken from OpenSSL 1.0.2d, which is [outdated & vulnerable for several years now](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-217/product_id-383/version_id-187773/Openssl-Openssl-1.0.2d.html). You should recompile their project with a more recent OpenSSL yourself if you want to be safe :). Or raise a ticket for them to update it.

Comment: @nightwish47 I just [successfully compiled it with the most recent OpenSSL 1.0.1v on Visual Studio 2016.](https://pstbin.ru/f/5613/). Unlike version they originally used, it haven't produced any errors. So I guess you should do the same..